# Swagger UI doesn't show embedded json properties model

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using the swagger tool for documenting my Jersey based REST API (the swaggerui I am using was downloaded on June 2014 don't know if this issue has been fixed in later versions but as I made a lot of customization to its code so I don't have the option to download the latest without investing lot of time to customize it again).

So far and until now, all my transfer objects have one level deep properties (no embedded pojos). But now that I added some rest paths that are returning more complex objects (two levels of depth) I found that SwaggerUI is not expanding the JSON model schema when having embedded objects.

Here is the important part of the swagger doc:

```
...
{
    "path": "/user/combo",
    "operations": [{
        "method": "POST",
        "summary": "Inserts a combo (user, address)",
        "notes": "Will insert a new user and a address definition in a single step",
        "type": "UserAndAddressWithIdSwaggerDto",
        "nickname": "insertCombo",
        "consumes": ["application/json"],
        "parameters": [{
            "name": "body",
            "description": "New user and address combo",
            "required": true,
            "type": "UserAndAddressWithIdSwaggerDto",
            "paramType": "body",
            "allowMultiple": false
        }],
        "responseMessages": [{
            "code": 200,
            "message": "OK",
            "responseModel": "UserAndAddressWithIdSwaggerDto"
        }]
    }]
}
...
"models": {
    "UserAndAddressWithIdSwaggerDto": {
        "id": "UserAndAddressWithIdSwaggerDto",
        "description": "",
        "required": ["user",
        "address"],
        "properties": {
            "user": {
                "$ref": "UserDto",
                "description": "User"
            },
            "address": {
                "$ref": "AddressDto",
                "description": "Address"
            }
        }
    },

    "UserDto": {
    "id": "UserDto",
    "properties": {
        "userId": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },...
    },

    "AddressDto": {
    "id": "AddressDto",
    "properties": {
        "addressId": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int64"
        },
        "street": {
            "type": "string"
        },...
    }

}
...
```

The embedded objects are User and Address, their models are being created correctly as shown in the json response.

But when opening the SwaggerUI I can only see:

```
{
  "user": "UserDto",
  "address": "AddressDto"
}
```

But I should see something like:

```
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "integer",
    "name": "string",...
  },
  "address": {
    "addressId": "integer",
    "street": "string",...
  }
}
```

Something may be wrong in the code that expands the internal properties, the javascript console doesn't show any error so I assume this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, there is a a line of code that needs to be modified to make it work properly:

In the swagger.js file there is a getSampleValue function with a conditional checking for undefined:

```
SwaggerModelProperty.prototype.getSampleValue = function(modelsToIgnore) {
  var result;
  if ((this.refModel != null) && (modelsToIgnore[this.refModel.name] === 'undefined'))
...
```

I updated the equality check to (removing quotes):

```
modelsToIgnore[this.refModel.name] === undefined
```

After that, SwaggerUI is able to show the embedded models.

Comment: running into the same problem but this is for a .net c# webapi application. I don't see this code in anything related to the swagger code.  Any suggestions?